# Firefox fetch API: How to omit the "origin" header in the request?

Tags: http, firefox, cors, firefox-addon-webextensions, fetch-api

If you make a fetch request in a Firefox WebExtension, it will automatically set the "origin" header. For example, when I run this code inside a WebExtensions ...

```
fetch('http://example.com/')
```

... the resulting request contains the header:
"origin: moz-extension://539a0d5b-60d9-4726-b3de-27d6979edc26"

Running the same code in Chromium will not set the header. (**Update:** This is not always true, as Chrome may also add the header: "origin: chrome-extension://...".)

**Is there an option to send the request without "origin"?**

---

I did not find an option in the fetch API. So, far the only solution that I see is to remove the header using the [webRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest), but that seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Firefox and Chrome automatically fill the `origin` header when a WebExtension sends a requests using the fetch API. There is currently no API option to prevent it.

If you do not want that behavior, you have two options:

1. Use the old [XMLHttpRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) instead of fetch
2. Manually strip the `origin` header using the [webRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest)

Option 1 will work, as the `origin` header is only set by the fetch API. For option 2, you will have to install an [`onBeforeSendHeaders`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeSendHeaders) handler to remove the header before the request leaves the browser:

```
function originWithId(header) {
  return header.name.toLowerCase() === 'origin' &&
         (header.value.indexOf('moz-extension://') === 0 ||
          header.value.indexOf('chrome-extension://') === 0);
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  (details) => {
    return {
      requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders.filter(x => !originWithId(x))
    }
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
);
```

To use the API, you will need to add `"webRequest"` and `"webRequestBlocking"` to the permissions in `manifest.json`.

Comment: It seems that Firefox now adds the origin header to XMLHttpRequests no matter what, and this no longer works...

Comment: @WilsonBiggs I tried on Firefox 69.0.1 and could not reproduce that XMLHttpRequest now sets the origin header. But I triggered the requests from the debug console while attached to an extension. I still got the origin header with fetch, though. Are you on a newer Firefox version, or is there another twist to reproduce? In any case, it would be sad if option 1 would stop working, as not all extensions have permission to use the webRequest API. That API gives a lot of power and adding it only for that purpose is hard to justify.

Comment: I think the issue was with something else, as after a rewrite of what I was working on this wasn't happening anymore. Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: Chrome now adds the Origin header with XMLHttpRequests too :/